# Iterating over nested list of equal elements

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists, with identical elements, created like this:

```
list1=[1,2,3]
list2=[]
for i in range(6):
    list2.append(list1)
list2
```

The outcome is:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

I want to be able to change the elements of the nested list; for example:

```
list2[0][0]=4
list2
```

produces:

```
[[4, 2, 3], [4, 2, 3], [4, 2, 3], [4, 2, 3], [4, 2, 3], [4, 2, 3]]
```

But I only want to change the first element of the first list:

```
[[4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

How can I do this ? What am I missing in the iterating process ?
At the end, I want to be able to reference any element in `list1`

Comment: @gibdud Indeed, the underlying problem was the same, but searching for my question did not find the duplicate one; and I think the two answers provided are simpler and slicker than the ones provided in the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way from your code is:

```
for i in range(6):
    list2.append(list1[:])
```

`[:]` does copy operation on list, so it's not the same list that you append everytime but a copy.

Comment: so basically I was creating a list of the same object - thus when changing one instance of that object I was changing all of them at the same time...?

Comment: @horace_vr, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

```
list2 = [[1,2,3] for i in range(6)]
list2[0][0]=4
print (list2)
```

output:

```
[[4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Was it really necessary to add a second answer to a duplicate question?

Comment: you are copying list1 in all items of list2 .and you have that list[0], list[1], list[2] are pointed on the same list (list1)

Comment: I was obviously too fast and I did not notice it as a duplicate @glibdud

Comment: @ncica your answer is correct and is working, but I will accept Austin's because is more in line with my code (list1 is an existing list)